# How to remove the dotted focus line from a TCustomListBox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a `TCustomListBox` derived control where I override the `DrawItem` procedure to give it a better look and feel.

One thing I have noticed, and it seems to affect the standard `TListBox` as well is that when the control is focused and there are no items it still draws the dotted focus line.

---

Here is a standard, unchanged `TListBox` with no items:

[image]

The dotted line is drawn when the control is focused (ie, clicked)

---

Now with my custom control the dotted lines still appear, only differently:

[image]

---

If my custom listbox contains items however, then no dotted lines are drawn:

[image]

---

Here is the main code for the custom listbox:

```
type
  TMyListBox = class(TCustomListBox)
  private
    FFillColor: TColor;
    FFrameColor: TColor;
  protected
    procedure DrawItem(Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyListBox }

constructor TMyListBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  FFillColor  := GetShadowColor(clMenuHighlight, 60);
  FFrameColor := GetShadowColor(clMenuHighlight, -20);

  Style := lbOwnerDrawVariable;
end;

destructor TMyListBox.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TMyListBox.DrawItem(Index: Integer; Rect: TRect;
  State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  Offset: Integer;
begin
  inherited;

  with (Self as TMyListBox) do
  begin
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect);

    if (odSelected in State) then
    begin
      Canvas.Pen.Color := FFrameColor;
      Canvas.Brush.Color := FFillColor;
      Canvas.Rectangle(Rect);
    end
    else
    begin
      Canvas.Pen.Color := Color;
      Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
      Canvas.Rectangle(Rect);
    end;

    Offset := (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top - Canvas.TextHeight(Items[Index])) div 2;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Canvas.Font.Color := Font.Color;
    Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + Offset + 2, Rect.Top + Offset, Items[Index]);
  end;
end;
```

What else do I need to do in order to remove the dotted focus line from the control?

Comment: This is the standard behaviour why do you want to change this? If you do not want to select the listbox without items simply disable the listbox

Comment: @SirRufo I understand your point but as I want the listbox to look good I need the dots removed. For what its worth I was thinking of having seperate item colors to indicate the listbox is not focused, kind of like how a listview looks (blue for focused, gray for non focused)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a handler for `WM_SETFOCUS` to prevent processing when there are no items:

```
procedure TMyListBox.WMSetFocus(var Message: TWMSetFocus);
begin
  Message.Result := 0;
  if Count <> 0 then
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: If you don't initialize, what will its value be?

Comment: Is this similar to setting TabStop to False?

Comment: @Blobby - Not really, it's for tab navigation.

Comment: @Blobby - However there still seems to be a issue, when there is at least one item but there's no selection, you can still see the focus rect when the box has the focus. We can't return from WM_SETFOCUS when there are items however.

Comment: @David - StdWndProc in classes.pas sets it to 0.